# TFS 2012 Uninstall does not remove the port 8080 bindings

Tags: binding, port, uninstallation

Quick background.  My client uses Visual Studio 2010 for their website.  It was ported onto a new machine, and I had to do some extensive work to get all of the 3rd party controls and add-ons to work.  They then requested source control, so using their MSDN license I pulled down and installed TFS 2012 on their machine.  Everything installed correctly, and seemed to work until I went to add the existing VS2010 project to TFS2012, and I got an error that when traced back, basically told me that I would not be able to use TFS 2012 and VS2010 together.  I weighed the choices, updating the project to VS2012, or uninstalling TFS 2012 and installing TFS2010, and decided the TFS route was the way to go, as I did not want to screw around with all the add-ons again.  TFS2012 uninstalled fine, and TFS2010 installed fine.

When I went to start configuring TFS2010, I got an error ([ Application Tier ] TF255297: The Web site found has bindings that conflict with the bindings chosen for the Web site for Team Foundation Server. You must manually resolve the conflict between the bindings.) basically telling me the binding were not removed for the TFS2012 install.  I looked in IIS and there is nothing in there using port 8080.

So my question is, how do I find out where the bindings are in use.  I tried the netstat commands, and did not find anything using port 8080.  I am kind of dead in the water here, so any help that is offered would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you putting your production application and TFS (source control) on the same server?

Comment: Client requested.  I offered other solutions but they insisted that the SQL Server, Application, and Source control all be located on a single server.  I am assuming it is a cost issue.